# В каком порядке итерпретатор python отработал код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, очередь

Начал изучать `python`. И не могу понять как узнать в каком порядке  отрабатывает скрипт:

```
# Очереди, модуль queue
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def worker(q, n):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        print("process data:", n, item)
        
q = Queue(5)
th1 = Thread(target=worker, args=(q, 1))
th2 = Thread(target=worker, args=(q, 2))
th1.start(); th2.start()

for i in range(50):
    q.put(i)
    
q.put(None); q.put(None)
th1.join(); th2.join()
```

Подскажите, как это выяснить?
Если можно приведите пример именно для кода выше...
ps `python3`, запускаю скрипт из терминала.

Comment: без явной синхронизации, порядок не определён. Более того print не является thread-safe поэтому вообще всё что угодно может получиться (к примеру [дополнительные строки могут печататься](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7687862/4279)). Попробуйте logging модуль использовать, чтобы оценить один из возможных путей исполнения¶ Вопрос не ясен: что вы под "порядком" понимаете когда у вас несколько потоков?

Comment: По существу, jfs прав. Маленькое замечание: старайтесь никогда не использовать точку с запятой в питоне. Новое выражение - в новой строке. Это явно не запрещено, но совершенно не принято. (Есть случаи, когда она нужно, но это, скорее, экзотика)

Comment: jfs, меня скорее интересует что и как отработает ДО тогда как начнут работать потоки и ПОСЛЕ.

Если я все равно непонятно выразился то так:
я не понимаю как в этом коде что-либо работает, хочу разобраться.
Разобраться в каком порядке что вызывается и что тут происходит.
И хочу понять как мне в будущем самостоятельно разбираться в том, как и что в скрипте.
В программировании не силен, в этом и загвоздка.

Comment: До `th1.start(); th2.start()` будет выполняться основной скрипт. После старта потоков будут выполняться еще и потоки "параллельно" (ага, как в пошаговой стратегии с [hot seat](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotseat)) со скриптом. В каком порядке что будет выполняться - не определено, может быть в любом.

Comment: @артурм. если вы не понимаете что происходит до запуска потоков, то стоит отдельный вопрос задать (один поток проще)¶ Информацию необходимую для ответа в сам вопрос помещайте (вопрос должен иметь смысл без комментариев). Можно на кнопку [edit] нажать